# groupBy and sortBy an array of object in native ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

We have an array of objects and we need to group these objects by group ID.

Then we need to obtain an array of array with sorted groups by timestamp.

This is the initial collection:

```
const arr = [
  {id: 'id1', group: '123', timestamp: 222},
  {id: 'id2', group: '123', timestamp: 999 },
  {id: 'id3', group: '456', timestamp: 333 },
  {id: 'id4', group: '789', timestamp: 111 },
  {id: 'id5', group: '554', timestamp: 555 },
];
```

The result we try to obtain is:

```
result = [
  [
    {id: 'id4', group: '789', timestamp: 111 }, 
  ],
  [
    {id: 'id1', group: '123', timestamp: 222},
    {id: 'id2', group: '123', timestamp: 999 },
  ],
  [
    {id: 'id3', group: '456', timestamp: 333 },
  ],
  [
    {id: 'id5', group: '554', timestamp: 555 },
  ]
]
```

We achieved that using Underscore.js but we are looking for a solution using native javascript and we struggled to pass from a reduced object to an array of array.

```
var groups = _(arr).chain()
    .groupBy("group")
    .sortBy((data) => _.first(data).timestamp)
    .value();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdsow1ph/

We tried to first group the items using such a method:

```
const groupBy = (arr, propertyToGroupBy) => {
    return arr.reduce((groups, item) => {
      const val = item[propertyToGroupBy];

      groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
      groups[val].push(item);

      return groups;
    }, {});
  }
```

But we obtain an unsortable object. So we need to convert that into array of array but we struggle to do that then apply sorting on the timestamp value.

Comment: It might be easier to sort it first and then group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to group the array into an object using the group as the key. Use `Object.values()` to convert the object into an array.

```js
const arr = [{"id":"id1","group":"123","timestamp":222},{"id":"id2","group":"123","timestamp":999},{"id":"id3","group":"456","timestamp":333},{"id":"id4","group":"789","timestamp":111},{"id":"id5","group":"554","timestamp":555}];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.group] = c[v.group] || [];
  c[v.group].push(v);
  return c;
}, {}));


console.log(result);
```

With `sort()`

```js
const arr = [{"id":"id4","group":"789","timestamp":111},{"id":"id1","group":"123","timestamp":222},{"id":"id3","group":"456","timestamp":333},{"id":"id5","group":"554","timestamp":555},{"id":"id2","group":"123","timestamp":999}]

var result = Object.values(
  arr
  .sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp)
  .reduce((c, v) => {
    c[v.group] = c[v.group] || [];
    c[v.group].push(v);
    return c;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks it works and then I can sort properly. Didn't think about Object.values!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Do you know how to then achieve a proper sorting to obtain a sorting by timestamp? I tried to apply a `.sort((a: any, b: any) => a[0].timestamp - b[0].timestamp)` on the result but it doesn't work if the original array was no sorted previously by timestamp

Comment: You can use `.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp)` for sorting :)

Comment: So the tip was to sort before and not after. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one line implementation in ES6 using [**Map object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = [ {id: 'id1', group: '123', timestamp: 222}, {id: 'id2', group: '123', timestamp: 999 }, {id: 'id3', group: '456', timestamp: 333 }, {id: 'id4', group: '789', timestamp: 111 }, {id: 'id5', group: '554', timestamp: 555 }, ];

const result = [...arr.reduce((r,c) => (r.set(c.group, r.has(c.group) ? 
  [...r.get(c.group), c] : [c]), r), new Map()).values()]

console.log(result)
```

For the sorting just prefix that reduce with a initial [**`sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const arr = [ {id: 'id1', group: '123', timestamp: 222}, {id: 'id2', group: '123', timestamp: 999 }, {id: 'id3', group: '456', timestamp: 333 }, {id: 'id4', group: '789', timestamp: 111 }, {id: 'id5', group: '554', timestamp: 555 }, ];

const result = [...arr.sort((a,b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp)
   .reduce((r,c) => (r.set(c.group, r.has(c.group) ? 
   [...r.get(c.group), c] : [c]), r), new Map()).values()]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Do you know about this solution's performance other accepted answer?

Comment: and do you know how then achieve a proper sorting on timestamp? I tried to apply `.sort((a: any, b: any) => a[0].timestamp - b[0].timestamp)` on the result your code gives me but it doesn't work properly if the original array is not already sorted by timestamp.

Comment: Not many people believe in the JS performance tests but here is one that shows it does pretty well: http://jsben.ch/xFrFE

Comment: Added the sort as well

Comment: In typescript 2.x I had to use `[...Array.from(arr.sort` to be able to spread :) because spreading a Map is not possible.

Comment: interesting. I guess to new of a feature for `typescript`. Ware you able to double check the performance. I am interested to find out if this one test I did is sufficient to rule this method faster or not?

Comment: Also weird that someone just went through the answers and down-voted all :(

Comment: I saw that... Stackoverflow mystery! I upvoted for sure. About performance, it's quite similar on my real life data with ~1000 rows. But your method remains more performant by small percent in our testing. We managed to get this working on TS using `downlevelIteration` compiler option. Thanks again for this great solution :)